# Fckeditor editor is not coming in cakephp V.3.2

Tags: cakephp, editor, cakephp-3.0, fckeditor, cakephp-3.x

I am using a Fckeditor ,but here fckeditor is not coming.I have used it in some of my php project.It was working fine.Here its showing error.
I have written following codes to do it.

```html
  <?php
                            echo $sBasePath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
                            $sBasePath = substr($sBasePath, 0, strpos($sBasePath, "_samples"));

                            $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('page_desc');
                            $oFCKeditor->Width = 790;
                            $oFCKeditor->Height = 300;
                            $oFCKeditor->BasePath = $sBasePath;
                            $oFCKeditor->Value = (stripslashes("hii"));
                            $oFCKeditor->Create();
                            ?>
```

and top of the page i have included

```html
<?php include_once("fckeditor/fckeditor.php"); ?>
```

In webroot folder ,i have inserted fckeditor folder content.

Fckeditor is not coming.Error is coming.
Here is the screenshorts  [image]

In line 50

```html
$page = $this->Pages->get($id, ['contain' => []]);
```

this code is present.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, always post the complete, exact error message _including_ the _full_ stacktrace! That being said, as you can see in the _partial_ stacktrace, the error is caused by a call in your pages controller on line 50, so you should check what's going on there and why. Also why are you trying to use FCKeditor anyways, it's an abandoned project which has long been superseded by [**CKEditor**](http://ckeditor.com/)!? See also **https://github.com/akkaweb/AKKA-CakePHP-CKEditor-Plugin**

Comment: Here in line 50 i have fetched data from data base.

Comment: This code is present.
$page = $this->Pages->get($id, ['contain' => []]);

Comment: the problem is that you don't have a record with that `$id` in your table.

Comment: I think here editor is coming,because of some error,its not showing.

Comment: No no i have record .@arilia

Comment: But obviously not the one that is being requested. Also you should check _why_ and _what_ record is being requested at that point. And again, please show the _full_ stacktrace if you expect anyone to be able to help you any further.